# Create a contact list from a site permission group in SP13?

Tags: 2013, permissions, contacts

Just like many others here I have been designated our command (or company) SCA with little experience and have been charged with designing the website.

Just as my title says, is there a way to create a contact list the feeds from a site permissions group (specifically the 'Contributors' group)?

I've tried applying the 'Site Users' web part but it doesn't display everything I need nor does it seem to be editable.

My end goal is a contact list which is fed by a site group and has columns that I can add information to which can be used to sort through groups of individuals.

By the way, I have been creeping this site for awhile now and want to thank all of you for your contributions!